# Angular 1.5.11 - ui router finds no state on init after upgrading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Running angular 1.15.11

When updating ui router from 0.3.1 to 1.0.8 in our application it seems like no state is being recognized from url.

```
StateService.current {
    name: "",
    url: "^"
}
```

All our states are registered in $state.router.stateRegistry.states and we also have configured a fallback url with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

in index.html

```
<div id="app" ui-view="main"></div>
```

In public-main.tpl.html

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

In private-main.tpl.html

```
<div ui-view="mobileHeader"></div>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
<div id="frame">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
<div ui-view="activityFeed"></div>
<div class="page-busy" ng-hide="!loading">
    <img src="assets/images/loading-bubbles-dark.svg">
</div>
```

We have an abstract public and private state.

```
.state('public', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'app/states/abstracts/public-main.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    data: {
        access: {
            isPrivate: false
        }
    }
})
.state('private', {
     abstract: true,
     views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'app/states/abstracts/private-main.tpl.html',
            controller: 'privateMainController'
        },
        'sidebar@private': {
            templateUrl: 'app/states/abstracts/sidebar.tpl.html',
            controller: 'sidebarController'
        },
        'activityFeed@private': {
             templateUrl: 'app/states/abstracts/activity-feed.tpl.html',
             controller: 'activityFeedController'
        },
        'mobileHeader@private': {
             templateUrl: 'app/states/abstracts/mobile-header.tpl.html',
             controller: 'mobileHeaderController'
        }
    },
    data: {
        access: {
           isPrivate: true
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        ...some resolves
    }
})
```

Our private root state, our dashboard is declared like:

```
$stateProvider.state('private.dashboard', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        templateUrl: 'app/states/dashboard/dashboard.tpl.html'
})
```

If a state.go('public.login') or $state.go('private.dashboard') is hardcoded in main controller the states are working fine, initiating checks for isLoggedIn and other stuff in 'onStateChange' functions. I know 'onStateChange' and others are deprecated in favour of transition events but they are re-enabled with $stateEvents.provider.enabled() and are working fine.

Before updating ui-router the app found a matching state on init based on the url provided in the browser, triggering onStateChange checking for login etc. Now no state is found and no view is applied.

Does anyone know if this has changed or how to enable it?

Comment: The initial state behavior *should work the same* in 1.x as in 0.3.1.  Try  toggling `$uiRouterProvider.trace.enable(1)` and see if there is an initial transition or any errors.  If not, stick a breakpoint here and see what shows up in the `best` variable . https://github.com/ui-router/core/blob/24da33201e55361e6e040b73306dd878e6f06b31/src/url/urlRouter.ts#L195

Comment: You might also try switching your setup to `.otherwise({ state: 'private.dashboard' })` instead of using the `/` url (see more here https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/url.urlrouter.html#otherwise )

Comment: Thank you for your input @ChrisT. I've had to leave the update project for a while to prioritize other tasks. I'll leave this open and revisit later for more questions or with a solution.